# Using mutate_at with mutate_if

Tags: r, dplyr, readr

I'm in the process of creating a generic function in my package.  The goal is to find columns that are percent columns, and then to use `parse_number` on them if they are `character` columns.  I haven't been able to figure out a solution using `mutate_at` and `ifelse`.  I've pasted a reprex below.

```r
 library(tidyverse)


df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~name, ~pass_percent, ~attendance_percent, ~grade,
  "Jon",         "90%",                0.85,    "B",
  "Jim",        "100%",                   1,    "A"
  )

percent_names <- df %>% select(ends_with("percent"))%>% names()


# Error due to attendance_percent already being in numeric value

if (percent_names %>% length() > 0) {
    df <-
      df %>%
      dplyr::mutate_at(percent_names, readr::parse_number)
  }
#> Error in parse_vector(x, col_number(), na = na, locale = locale, trim_ws = trim_ws): is.character(x) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your `attendance_percent` variable is numeric, not character and `parse_number` only wants character variables, see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/921). So a solution would be:

```
edited_parse_number <- function(x, ...) {
  if (mode(x) == 'numeric') {
    x
  } else {
    parse_number(x, ...)
  }
}


df %>%
  dplyr::mutate_at(vars(percent_names), edited_parse_number)

#  name  pass_percent attendance_percent grade
#  <chr>        <dbl>              <dbl> <chr>
#1 Jon             90               0.85 B    
#2 Jim            100               1    A
```

OR

if you didn't want to use that extra function, extract character variables at beginning:

```
percent_names <- df %>% 
  select(ends_with("percent")) %>% 
  select_if(is.character) %>% 
  names()
percent_names
# [1] "pass_percent"


df %>%
  dplyr::mutate_at(vars(percent_names), parse_number)
#   name  pass_percent attendance_percent grade
#   <chr>        <dbl>              <dbl> <chr>
# 1 Jon             90               0.85 B    
# 2 Jim            100               1    A
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, without having to create a function, you can just add an `ifelse` statement into `mutate_at` such as:

```r
if (percent_names %>% length() > 0) {
  df <-
    df %>% rowwise() %>%
    dplyr::mutate_at(vars(percent_names), ~ifelse(is.character(.), 
                                                  parse_number(.),
                                                  .))
}

Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  name  pass_percent attendance_percent grade
  <chr>        <dbl>              <dbl> <chr>
1 Jon             90               0.85 B    
2 Jim            100               1    A
```

Comment: this is neater than my answer but your final `.` is changing your numbers in your output?

Comment: Ok, I corrected it by adding `rowwise` first. But not sure about the logic behind that.

Comment: Thanks, but what does rowwise do?

Comment: You're welcome ;). `rowwise` will evaluate the dataframe rows by rows (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rowwise.html). Not sure, why it is required here but it seems that the `ifelse` statement will evaluate the first rows of columns of `percent_names` and then apply the TRUE or FALSE conditions to the first rows.